# nextauth.js is not authenticating through google

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, google-oauth

I am new nextjs and I am trying to use the nextauth.js for the google authentication in my web application and while login through email I am getting error-http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?error=OAuthCallback[error telling to login with different account and also I have tried with different account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMG4t.png)

I am attaching snippets of code with this below-:
[code snippet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0OTs.png)
[code snippet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQSPw.png)

PS. I have already doubled checked the google secret id.

I was supposed to enter the session if the login would be authenticated.

// FOR FILE NAME LOGIN.tsx

```
'use client'
import { signIn }  from "next-auth/react";
import Image from "next/image";

function Login() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-[#11A37F] h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-center">
       <Image
        src="https://links.papareact.com/2is"
        width={300}
        height={300}
        alt="logo"
       />
       <button  onClick={() =>  signIn('google')} className="text-white font-bold text-3xl animate-pulse">Sign In to use ChatGEN</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

// For FILE NAME [...nextauth].ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"

export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET!,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code"
    }}}),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.